# ZPL Can I trick the printer into thinking I printed two labels?

Tags: label, zpl, zpl-ii

I have a label stock that has two labels side by side, so I've written my code to print identically on both of these labels.

The issue is that a printer sees this as one label, but I need it to see them as two.  How then, could I possibly trick the printer into thinking two labels have been printed?

If ZPL can print 2 separate pieces of code on one label this might be possible.  If there's a command that makes a single label count as 2 then it's definitely possible.

Comment: Do you want the display to say 2 of 2 rather than 1 of 2? Or what mechanism are you trying to trick?

Comment: The problems is that we have an automated system that will print 2 labels (since they are side by side) but it will count automatically them as one label.  

What I'm looking for is a way to make the printer think that it has printed 2 labels, because it actually has.   I'd have to do this in ZPL though, and I don't know if it's possible.